# author.php added to template not working on Nginx server

Tags: templates, author

I'm using a theme with no author template.

According to [Author Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates),

> In the case of authors, the hierarchy is fairly simple. The Template
>   Hierarchy specifies that WordPress uses the first Template file it
>   finds in your current Theme's directory from the following list:
>
> ```
> author-{nicename}.php - If the author's nice name were rami, WordPress would look for author-rami.php.
> author-{id}.php - If the author's ID were 6, WordPress would look for author-6.php.
> author.php
> archive.php
> index.php
> ```
>
> That is, if you do not have an author.php file, WordPress will check
>   for archive.php, and so on.

Well, I created `author.php` and `author-username.php` file (for test) and put them in `wp-content/themes/mytemplate/`.

But when I try `mysite.com/author/username` WordPress redirects to index page.

I'm using Nginx as my web server.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect to index page"? The URL changes and you are sent to a different page?

Comment: @abkrim about "redirect to index page" - do you mean your URL is redirecting to the `home` page (`mysite.com`) or do you mean even after adding author templates your `index.php` template is loading? Please clarify.

Comment: @Fayaz if use `mysite.com/author/username` webserver redirect to `mysite.com`

Comment: I think I understood your problem. Final question before I answer: what happened before you created `author.php` & `author-username.php` author template files? I mean were they redirecting to home page even before creating those author templates? Or are they only redirecting after you created the author templates?

Answer (score 2):

According to your scenario: most likely a Plugin is doing the redirect from the `author archive` page to the `home` page.

For example: Yoast SEO Plugin is know to cause a similar issue. If you are using [Yoast SEO Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/), then Go to Yoast `SEO` Menu from your WordPress admin panel & then:

> Go to `Titles & metas` => `Archives`
>
> Then uncheck `Disable the author archives` if it is checked.

Then try the author link (clear browser cache if it doesn't work immediately).

> `Disable the author archives` | `Enable the author archives` option may also be in:
>
> `SEO Menu` => `Titles & metas` => `Others`
>
> (depending on your version of the plugin)

If it doesn't work, then try disabling plugins one by one to find out which of the plugins is causing the redirect.

> ***NOTE:*** Every time you disable a plugin to test if the redirect is still happening, take the following two steps to be sure:
>
> 1. Clear browser cache.
> 2. Clear WordPress Rewrite rules from:
>
> `Admin Menu` => `Settings` => `Permalinks`
>
> then click `Save Changes` button without making any change from there.

Once you identify the problematic plugin, find if it has any option to enable / disable author archives & take action accordingly.

Comment: A lot of thanks. Not work for me. Work fine if `Enable the author archives` Apreciate your time [Author page](https://wikired.es/author/abkrim/)

Comment: @abkrim you said "Not work for me". Didn't you mean: "Now works for me"? Just saying because it may be confusing for future visitors with similar issues :)